# Servidor não encontra a ROTA do app NODE.JS

Tags: node.js

sou novo no node.js e estou com um problema, uma dúvida que pode ser banal, mas como estou iniciando não consigo resolver. Se puderem me auxiliar ...

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em node, rodando 100% certo localhost, mas agora para subir para o server cPanel não estou conseguindo.

Fiz todos os procedimentos conforme esse tutorial deles
https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

O teste deles funcionou 100% deu tudo certo

Mas agora não sei como "traduzir" a minha rota local para essa que eles usam no server

A rota está assim:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html');
})
```

Pelo tutorial deveria ser algo talvez algo como isso:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html');
});
```

Mas da erro.

O engraçado ou não é que no terminal quando deixo a rota como no primeiro caso que é o mesmo do localhost eu recebo o código do arquivo HTML que quero renderizar na rota principal quando faço o teste que eles pedem ali jogando no terminal "curl [http://127.0.0.1:3000"](http://127.0.0.1:3000%22),

Porém no link específico que criei para o app da erro de rota cannot GET /fino (fino é o nome do app)

A estrutura dos arquivos está assim:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7ktG.png)

Dentro da pasta src está o arquivo index.html

Espero que tenha sido claro na pergunta

Comment: O seu plano de hospedagem cobre rodar um server? Pq ás vezes o plano só cobre arquivos estáticos e não um server

Comment: Não tenho essa resposta de pronto Rodrigo, preciso verificar com a equipe de server lá, mas acredito que sim, pois ao fazer o teste conforme o tutorial deles ele abre o "hello word" normal

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom dia amigo!

> Se você já tem a aplicação funcionando corretamente em ambiente local
> utilizando o Express, não há necessidade de mudar a rota no servidor
> cPanel para o http.createServer. Basta certificar-se de que a rota
> está configurada corretamente no servidor.

O erro que você está recebendo, "`cannot GET /fino`", indica que a rota que você está tentando acessar não está definida no seu código.

Você definiu a rota padrão "**/**", mas não a rota "**/fino**". Para corrigir isso, você precisa definir a rota "**/fino**" no seu código.

Por exemplo, você pode adicionar o seguinte código:

```
app.get('/fino', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html');
})
```

Isso define a rota "**/fino**" e envia o arquivo "**index.html**" quando essa rota for acessada.

Certifique-se de que o caminho do arquivo esteja correto. Se o arquivo "**index.html**" estiver dentro da pasta "**src**", como você mencionou, o código acima deve funcionar corretamente.

**Explicando:**

Pelo que entendi, você está tentando subir uma aplicação Node.js em um servidor cPanel e está tendo dificuldades com as rotas. Vou tentar te ajudar a entender o que pode estar acontecendo.

Quando você executa o comando `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` no terminal, está acessando a rota principal da sua aplicação, que você definiu como **/**. Mas quando tenta acessar a rota específica do seu aplicativo, que pelo que entendi é **/fino**, está recebendo o erro "`cannot GET /fino`".

Isso pode estar acontecendo por alguns motivos:

1. Você não configurou a rota corretamente no seu servidor cPanel. Certifique-se de que está utilizando a mesma rota que utilizou no seu ambiente local.
2. Você não iniciou o servidor corretamente no servidor cPanel. Certifique-se de que o servidor está rodando na porta correta e que as configurações estão corretas.
3. Algum erro no seu código está impedindo a aplicação de funcionar corretamente. Verifique se não há erros de sintaxe ou lógica na sua aplicação.

Sobre as diferenças entre as rotas no seu ambiente local e no servidor cPanel, o que você definiu inicialmente utilizando o **Express** `(app.get('/', (request, response) => { ... }))` é uma rota que responde a **requisições GET na rota raiz do seu aplicativo**. Já o que você viu no tutorial, utilizando o **http.createServer**, é um exemplo de como criar um servidor HTTP básico sem a utilização do Express.

Se você já tem a aplicação funcionando corretamente em ambiente local utilizando o Express, não há necessidade de mudar a rota no servidor cPanel para o **http.createServer**. Basta certificar-se de que a rota está configurada corretamente no servidor.

Comment: Conforme dito estou negativando até que autor da reposta remova as saudações.

Comment: Muito obrigado @obama fiz a alteração e fiz deploy de novo da aplicação, funcionou no navegador, quando coloco no terminal "curl http://127.0.0.1:3000" ele da erro de rota, mas entendi, que quando é no terminal ele pega a raiz e pelo navegador ele pega a rota /fino, muito obrigado por sua resposta e esclarecimentos, abriu mais aqui a mente, valeu Mestre!